# Problema con texto de salida desde un constructor

Tags: c++, poo, clase, objeto, class

No puedo imprimir un texto `cout<<"hola";` desde un constructor.
Creé una clase `Nueva_clase` con un constructor por defecto.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Nueva_clase{
    private:
        int num;
    public:
        Nueva_clase(){
            cout<<"hola";
        }
};
```

Esta es la función principal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Nueva_clase.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Nueva_clase p();

    return 0;
}
```

Cuando compilo, supongo que debería imprimir `hola`, pero nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debes utilizar `()` después del nombre de la variable, basta con que la declares para que se cree una instancia:

```
int main(){

    Nueva_clase p;

    return 0;
}
```

Por otro lado, al compilar no tiene que imprimirse más que los mensajes que de el compilador. El `'hola'` se imprimirá cuando ejecutes el programa compilado. Es probable que es lo que hayas querido decir, pero para hacer la distinción, pues son acciones distintas. Puedes compilar sin ejecutar y, una vez compilado, puedes ejecutar sin volver a compilar.